# The integral closure of a field is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have the following problem

> Let $R \subset S$. Let $S'$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $S$. If $R$ is a field, then $S'$ is a field.

I've seen that integral closures are automatically closed under addition and multiplication, so we just need to find inverses. If we pick any $s \in S'$, then $s$ satisfies some monic $f(x) \in R[x]$ by definition.

Hence $f(s) = r_0 + r_1s + \cdots + s^n = 0$. If we rearrange, we get that $r_0 = s(-r_1 - r_2s - \cdots - s^{n-1})$. If we multipliy through by $r_{0}^{-1}$, we get that $s^{-1} = (\frac{-1}{r_0}(r_1 + r_2s + \cdots + s^{n-1}))$.

This seems to work only if $r_0$ is non zero. What do we do if $r_0 =0$?

Comment: What do you mean by the integral closure of a field? I know what it means to take the integral closure of a subring $A$ inside a bigger ring $B$ (commutativity assumed everywhere), and I know what it means to take the integral closure of an integral domain $D$ (take the integral closure in the field of fractions). But a field is its own field of fractions, so the integral closure in this sense of a field is immediately itself with no further work required. Are you taking the integral closure of the field in its algebraic closure?

Comment: In any case, if $r_0 = 0$ then $0 = s(-r_1 - \dots - s^{n-1})$. Since I assume these calculations are still taking place inside an integral domain, either $s = 0$ or $r_1 + \dots + s^{n-1} = 0$. Continuing in this way, if $s \neq 0$ then $r_0 \neq 0$ WLOG. If you're taking the integral closure in the algebraic closure it's not hard to see that in fact you just get the entire algebraic closure.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah, I've made a mistake with my wording. I mean an integral closure inside a larger ring. Let me make an edit.

Comment: Perhaps see Prop 2.1.10 of https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/ComAlg/ComAlg2.pdf

Comment: @QiaochuYuan of course! The fact that it was a domain completely slipped my mind. Thank you!

Comment: Once you've reduced to the case where $r_0 \ne 0$, another way to proceed would be to show that $s^{-1}$ is a root of $t^n + r_0^{-1} r_1 t^{n-1} + r_0^{-1} r_2 t^{n-2} + \cdots + r_0^{-1} r_{n-1} t + r_0^{-1}$.

Comment: Unless you _assume_ $S$ to have no nilpotents, I think this is wrong. Let $S=R[x]/(x^2)$, then $x^2=0$ is a monic relation for $x$ with coefficients in $R$ and so $x\in S'$, so $S'$ cannot be a field.